# How to compare two xml files and display the difference side by side using nodejs or javascript

Tags: javascript, node.js, xml, typescript, xml-parsing

I have two Xml documents, now I need to find the difference between them and after getting the differences I need to return the Xpaths of the different comparisons.
How to approach this problem using nodejs or javascript.

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Answer (score -1):

You should be able to do this with JavaScript. Loop or recurse through both files and maintain the xpath as you go.

Comment: Can you give an example code snippet how to approach the problem.like how to maintain the xpaths with recursion